# cURL Login - Not working with @ in email input

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use cURL to login to a website, but it doesn't seem to be working. I started by testing it on my own site which works, but when I try on the site that I actually need it wont login, and just gets the login page.

```
$loginUrl = 'https://www.ekomi.co.uk/login.php';
$postData = 'login_email=-----&login_passwort=-----';

$ch = curl_init();
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookies.txt');

$postResult = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($postResult);
```

It does give an error that $_SERVER index is undefined, but it still allowed me to login to my site, also I am assuming that the $postData should be the names of the user and password fields.

Is there anything wrong with the script that could be the problem, or could it maybe be the way which the site logs in?

**Edit**

The problem seems to be because of the @ symbol in the login email, I've tried putting %40 as suggested in other questions but this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you running this script from command-line or webserver?

Comment: @Edward144 use the full path for cookie file name instead of the relative path. i.e. c:/xyz/cookies/cookies.txt

Comment: No, It's still not working unfortunately

Comment: The fields do have javascript on them which removes the value on click. Colud that be causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you must navigate to the page and get the csrf (**Cross-site request forgery**-basically it checks that the login form is seen by the user, sets a random hash in the session and checks if you give it back) and then make the post.
[image: check the request]